# How can i custom sort my table by MoSCoW priority using DataTables?

Tags: html, datatables, columnsorting

I am currently creating an Agile Scrum project management web application.
I am displaying a list of stories in a table with one column being their priority in MoSCow (Must, Should, Could and Won't)
I am new to datatables and wondered how i would go about ordering by a custom data set [Must, Should, Could, Wont]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom sort filter should do the trick, something like this:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "moscow-pre": function ( a ) {
        var vals = ["Won't","Could","Should","Must"];
        return $.inArray(a, vals);
    },
    "moscow-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "moscow-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/18781Let/). Hope that helps.